# IBMLogger and checking logging in the Bluemix console

Tags: ibm-cloud

I'm building a hybrid app that speaks to a Bluemix app. I've got Mobile Application Security and Mobile Quality Assurance as a service. I'm using IBMLogger to send log messages, like so:

```
IBMBluemix.getLogger().info("Device successfully registered: "+ JSON.stringify(response));
```

I was under the impression that the MobileFirst-style services on Bluemix acted somewhat like the same components for a local MF install. I'm trying to find where I can see my log files in the BM console but have not been able to find them.

For a local MF install using the hybrid SDK, you have to specifically say you want your logs sent to the server, but I do not see that option when looking at the hybrid docs for BM/MF.

Answer (score 0):

There is some doc here: https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/starters/mobile/mobilecloud/nodejsmobile.html#log

I suppose by default the log goes to the console, which you can retrieve through the loggregator, aka do `cf logs <yourapp> --recent`. You can also use the Monitoring & Analytics service to retain logs - see the above doc.

Comment: Hmm. It says this for persisting, "With Monitoring and Analytics for IBM Bluemix you can collect log messages with the loganalysis NPM module." That seems to imply that you can only persist log messages from the Node.js side, not the hybrid side. Is that right? If so, why would a developer bother using the logger on the client side over just using the plain console object?